# grpc-gateway: how to set allowed content-type per request

Tags: http, go, grpc, grpc-gateway

I'm using `grpc-gateway` inside same go app, to proxy convert HTTP to GRPC. As far as I see by default `grpc-gateway` sets application `application/json` format for all rpcs, including streaming.

So, my task is:

1. Incoming HTTP requests MUST always be `Content-type: application/json`, otherwise request should be rejected and 406 sent according to RFC.
2. Incoming HTTP request MAY have `Accept: application/x-ndjson` set for unary RPCs and `Accept: applcation/x-ndjson` header set for server streams. If conditions don't met 406, should be returned.
3. Outgoing HTTP request MUST set `Content-type: applicaiton/json`, for simple unary RPCs, and `Content-type: application/x-ndjson` for server streams.

So, `grpc-gateway` proposes only to set custom marshaller, for `application/x-ndjson`, which would do actually the same as default one, so with just overwritten `ContentType` method. This approach not allowing me to set marshaler per method call, and doesn't allow me to reject unsupported content type per request.

How can I achieve this still using `grpc-gateway`? Or I should consider then implementing http grpc conversion manually?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not use the grpc-gateway or any other tool to convert gRPC to HTTP RPC. You are adding unnecessary complexity to your application.

If you have a gRPC service but for whatever reason, your client can not call the gRPC and you need to offer your service through a plain HTTP option... Is that your case?

If that is your case the correct way is to offer an HTTP RPC service and from it, you call your gRPC service.

HTTP RPC is way simpler than REST and you don't need any tool for that.

I have this exact case implemented in GOlang [here](https://github.com/apssouza22/modern-api-management/blob/master/services/book/http/v1/handler.go#L23)

```
    // Creates a new book.
func (h BookStoreService) CreateBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    request := &bookv1.CreateBookRequest{}
    proxy := httputil.GetProxy(w, r, request)
    proxy.SetServiceRequest(func(request proto.Message) (proto.Message, error) {
        return h.client.CreateBook(r.Context(), request.(*bookv1.CreateBookRequest))
    })
    proxy.Call()
}
```

Proxy struct

```
func GetProxy(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, request proto.Message) *ServiceProxy {
    proxy := &ServiceProxy{}
    proxy.SetResponseWriter(w)
    proxy.SetSourceRequest(r)
    proxy.SetDestRequest(request)
    return proxy
}

type ServiceProxy struct {
    err            error
    serviceRequest func(request proto.Message) (proto.Message, error)
    writer         http.ResponseWriter
    destRequest    proto.Message
    sourceRequest  *http.Request
}

func (b *ServiceProxy) SetDestRequest(request proto.Message) {
    b.destRequest = request
}

func (b *ServiceProxy) SetSourceRequest(request *http.Request) {
    b.sourceRequest = request
}

func (b *ServiceProxy) SetServiceRequest(svcRequest func(request proto.Message) (proto.Message, error)) *ServiceProxy {
    b.serviceRequest = svcRequest
    return b
}

func (b *ServiceProxy) Call() {
    b.writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    err := unmarshal(b.writer, b.sourceRequest, b.destRequest)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    resp, err := b.serviceRequest(b.destRequest)
    if err != nil {
        handleErrorResp(b.writer, err)
        return
    }
    b.writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    json.NewEncoder(b.writer).Encode(resp)
}

func (b *ServiceProxy) SetResponseWriter(w http.ResponseWriter) {
    b.writer = w
}
```

Comment: Also think that grpc gateway is overkill for most use cases